# Rewrite neo4j queries for OrientDB

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, orientdb-2.1, nosql

I'm testing performance neo4j vs OrientDB graph DBs. I'm using MoiveDatabase dataset available on neo4j site. I've followed the instructions:

```
export-graphml -t -o /tmp/out.graphml
CREATE DATABASE plocal:/tmp/db/test
IMPORT DATABASE /tmp/out.graphml storeVertexIds=true
```

Here is `classes` output so I guess import was OK.

```
CLASSES
----------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 NAME                 | SUPERCLASS                         | CLUSTERS   | RECORDS        |
----------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 ACTS_IN              | [E]                                | 14         |          94700 |
 DIRECTED             | [E]                                | 13         |          11915 |
 E                    |                                    | 10         |              0 |
 FRIEND               | [E]                                | 16         |              6 |
 Movie                | [V]                                | 12         |           6379 |
 OFunction            |                                    | 6          |              0 |
 OIdentity            |                                    | -          |              0 |
 ORestricted          |                                    | -          |              0 |
 ORIDs                |                                    | 8          |              0 |
 ORole                | [OIdentity]                        | 4          |              3 |
 OSchedule            |                                    | 7          |              0 |
 OTriggered           |                                    | -          |              0 |
 OUser                | [OIdentity]                        | 5          |              3 |
 Person               | [V]                                | 11         |          50013 |
 RATED                | [E]                                | 15         |             30 |
 V                    |                                    | 9          |          61752 |
----------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 TOTAL = 16                                                                       224801 |
----------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

But when I try to execute this query:
`SELECT in() FROM Movie LIMIT 10` or `SELEC out() FROM Person LIMIT 10` I don't get any records. Why is that?

I'm trying to rewrite co-actors query:

```
 MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor:Person)
 RETURN coActor.name
```

and "co-co-actors" query:

```
MATCH (tom:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie1)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor:Person),
(coActor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coCoActor:Person)
WHERE tom.name = "Tom Hanks" AND   NOT    (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie2)

RETURN coCoActor.name
```

Should I use `TRAVERSE` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this small DB to try your case:

```
create class Person extends V
create class Movie extends V
create class acts_In extends E
create class directed extends E
create class friend extends E
create class rated extends E

create property Person.name String
create property Person.surname String
create property Movie.title String

create vertex Person set name="Tom", surname="Hanks"
create vertex Person set name="Robin", surname="Wright"
create vertex Person set name="Helen", surname="Hunt"
create vertex Person set name="Robert", surname="Zemeckis"
create vertex Person set name="Russell", surname="Crowe"
create vertex Person set name="Ben", surname="Affleck"
create vertex Person set name="Kevin", surname="Macdonald"
create vertex Person set name="John"
create vertex Person set name="Mark"
create vertex Person set name="Paul"
create vertex Person set name="Mel", surname="Gibson"
create vertex Person set name="Nancy", surname="Meyers"
create vertex Movie set title="Forrest Gump"
create vertex Movie set title="Cast Away"
create vertex Movie set title="State of Play"
create vertex Movie set title="What Women Want"

create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Tom" and surname="Hanks") to (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Tom" and surname="Hanks") to (select from Movie where title="Cast Away")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Robin" and surname="Wright") to (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Robin" and surname="Wright") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt") to (select from Movie where title="Cast Away")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt") to (select from Movie where title="What Women Want")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Mel" and surname="Gibson") to (select from Movie where title="What Women Want")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Russell" and surname="Crowe") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Ben" and surname="Affleck") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge friend from (select from Person where name="Mel" and surname="Gibson") to (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt")
create edge friend from (select from Person where name="Ben" and surname="Affleck") to (select from Person where name="Russell" and surname="Crowe")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="What Women Want") to (select from Person where name="Nancy" and surname="Meyers")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="Cast Away") to (select from Person where name="Robert" and surname="Zemeckis")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump") to (select from Person where name="Robert" and surname="Zemeckis")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="State of Play") to (select from Person where name="Kevin" and surname="Macdonald")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="What Women Want") to (select from Person where name="Paul")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="Cast Away") to (select from Person where name="John")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump") to (select from Person where name="Mark")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="State of Play") to (select from Person where name="John")
```

**First query**: find the co-actor of Tom Hanks

```
select distinct(name) as name, distinct(surname) as surname from (select expand(in('acts_In')) from Movie where in('acts_In').name in 'Tom' 
and in('acts_In').surname in 'Hanks') where name<>'Tom' and in('acts_In').surname<>'Hanks'
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+-----+-------
#   |@CLASS|name |surname
----+------+-----+-------
0   |null  |Robin|Wright
1   |null  |Helen|Hunt
----+------+-----+-------
```

**Second query**: find the co-co-actor with whom Tom Hanks hasn't starred

```
select name, surname from (select expand($ris)
let $a=(select from Person where out('acts_In').size()>0 and name<>'Tom' and surname<>'Hanks'),
    $b=(select from (select expand(in('acts_In')) from Movie where in('acts_In').name in 'Tom' and in('acts_In').surname in 'Hanks') where name<>'Tom' and in('acts_In').surname<>'Hanks'),
    $ris=difference($a,$b))
```

**Output**:

```
----+------+-------+-------
#   |@CLASS|name   |surname
----+------+-------+-------
0   |null  |Russell|Crowe
1   |null  |Ben    |Affleck
2   |null  |Mel    |Gibson
----+------+-------+-------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me to figure out how it should work. I will mark answer as correct and please update first query where you have twice `in('acts_In').name in 'Tom'`. I guess you should have surname.

Comment: Hi, thank you for voting and for pointing, I've just edited my answer. Do you have a chance to try the queries ? Thanks